# Proof of topological space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

My solution:

1) $ cl(A) \subseteq  cl(cl(A))$

let $x \in cl(cl(A))$ by definition $U_x \cap cl(A) \neq \varnothing $ $ \forall U_x \in Tau$  such that $x\in U_x $ .Thus $x \in cl(cl(A))$
$cl(A) \subseteq cl(cl(A))$
Is it true? And how prove other side.

Comment: And of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925783/is-the-closure-of-a-set-equal-to-the-closure-of-the-closure-of-that-set?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: For the easy side: $B \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(B)$ for all $B$ is obvious. Apply for $B = \operatorname{cl}(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{cl}(A)) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(A)$ directly using your definition:

Suppose $x \in \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{cl}(A))$, and suppose we have some open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$.  Then, by the definition, $\operatorname{cl}(A) \cap U_x \ne \emptyset$.  Choose some $y \in \operatorname{cl}(A) \cap U_x$.  Then, since $y \in U_x$ and $U_x$ is open, we see that $U_x$ is also an open neighborhood of $y$; and since $y \in \operatorname{cl}(A)$, applying the definition again, we get that $A \cap U_x \ne \emptyset$.  In conclusion, we have shown that for any open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$, then $A \cap U_x \ne \emptyset$, which by definition means that $x \in \operatorname{cl}(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

In your proof I don't see why $\mathrm{cl}(A)\subseteq \mathrm{cl}\mathrm{cl}(A)$ follows. You need to start with $x\in \mathrm{cl}(A)$. Let me give you some hints.

First, for every subset $A\in X$, $A\subseteq \mathrm{cl}(A)$ is always true. For every $x\in A$, observe that every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ will intersect with $A$.

To prove $\mathrm{cl}(A) \supseteq \mathrm{cl}\mathrm{cl}(A)$, prove that
$$
\mathrm{cl}(A)= \bigcap_{C\textrm{ closed}\\C\supseteq A}C
$$
$\mathrm{cl}(A)$ is a closed set because it is an intersection of closed sets, and since $\mathrm{cl}\mathrm{cl}(A)$ is an intersection of closed sets containing $\mathrm{cl}(A)$, $\mathrm{cl}(A)$ must contain $\mathrm{cl}\mathrm{cl}(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

$cl(A)$ is the intersections of all closed sets which contains $A$ and so $cl(A)$ is closed and obviously $A\subset cl(A)$ $\ldots (1)$.

And if $A$ is closed, since one of the closed sets which contains $A$ is also $A$, we have   $cl(A)\subset A$. By (1) we can say  $cl(A)= A$$\ldots (2)$.

By using (1),   $cl(A)$ is closed, then by using (2) $cl(cl(A))=cl(A)$